# Jetpack Compose DynamicForm State Handling

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Hello i have been working on a dynamic composable form

## This is my main screen

```
@SuppressLint("UnrememberedMutableState")
@Preview
@Composable
fun LoanFormScreen(navController: NavController = rememberNavController()) {
    val api = API
    val loanForm: MutableState<LoanForm?> = remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val currentStep = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val form = loanForm.value?.successNotification?.steps?.getOrNull(currentStep.value)
    val stepFieldsList = form?.values?.firstOrNull()?.fields ?: listOf()
    val data = breakdownStepFields(stepFieldsList)

    MainScaffold(
        title = "",
        isDefaultColumn = false,
        content = {
            LoanFormContent(currentStep, data)
        },
        navController = navController
    )

    SideEffect {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            loanForm.value = api.loadLoanApplicationForm()
        }
    }
}
```

## This is where the content goes to

```
@SuppressLint("UnrememberedMutableState")
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
private fun LoanFormContent(
    currentStep: MutableState<Int>,
    data: MutableMap<String, Pair<TextFieldState, @Composable () -> Unit>>
) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(mainSurfaceColor)
            .padding(horizontal = 15.dp),
    ) {
        Card(
            backgroundColor = Color.White,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.loan_application_form),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = 25.dp),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Card(
            backgroundColor = Color.White,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp)
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(15.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
            ) {
                if (data.isEmpty()) {
                    item {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                        ) {
                            CircularProgressIndicator()
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    data.forEach { (key, value) ->
                        item {
                            value.second()
                        }
                    }
                    item {
                        Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                            if (currentStep.value > 0) {
                                CustomButton(
                                    text = "Previous",
                                    onClick = {
                                        currentStep.value--
                                    },
                                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                                )
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(2.dp))
                            }
                            CustomButton(
                                text = if (currentStep.value == data.size - 1) "Finish" else "Next",
                                onClick = {
                                    val currentStepData =
                                        data.map { it.value.first.validate() }
                                    if (!currentStepData.all { it }) {
                                        if (currentStep.value == data.size - 1) {
                                            val jsonFormData = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
                                            data.forEach { (key, value) ->
                                                jsonFormData[key] = value.first.value
                                            }
                                            Log.e("json", jsonFormData.toString())
                                        } else {
                                            currentStep.value++
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
    }
}
```

## Here is the dynamic form builder

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
private fun breakdownStepFields(stepFieldsList: List<Field>): MutableMap<String, Pair<TextFieldState, @Composable () -> Unit>> {
    val textFieldStatesMap = mutableMapOf<String, Pair<TextFieldState, @Composable () -> Unit>>()

    stepFieldsList.forEach { field ->
        val key = field.key
        val label = field.label
        val hint = field.hint
        val type = field.type
        val isRequired = field.isRequired
        val regex = field.regex
        val dropdownItems = field.dropdownItems?.map { item -> item.value ?: "" }?.toList()
            ?: listOf()
        val options = field.options?.map { option -> option.value ?: "" }?.toList() ?: listOf()
        val dependentOn = field.dependentOn
        val dependencyValues = field.dependencyValues
        val dependentValueRequired = field.dependentValueRequired

        val state: TextFieldState = TextFieldState(
            name = label?.en.toString(),
            validators = if (type?.contains("radio") == true || type?.contains("dropdown") == true) listOf()
            else listOf(
                Validators.Custom(message = regex?.err?.en.toString(), function = {
                    it.toString().matches(Regex(regex?.value ?: ""))
                })
            )
        )

        val dependentFieldState = textFieldStatesMap[dependentOn]
        val isDisabled =
            dependentFieldState != null && dependentValueRequired == true && (dependentFieldState.first.value.isEmpty() || !dependencyValues?.contains(
                dependentFieldState.first.value
            )!!)

        val textFieldBuilder: @Composable () -> Unit = {
            CustomField(
                label = label?.en ?: "",
                hint = hint?.en ?: "",
                state = state,
                onValueChange = { state.change(it) },
                isNumberInput = type?.contains("number") ?: false,
                isDropDownField = type?.contains("dropdown") ?: false,
                dropDownMenuItems = dropdownItems,
                isRadioBox = type?.contains("radio") ?: false,
                radioButtonItems = options,
                isFile = type?.contains("file") ?: false,
                isDisabled = isDisabled,
            )
        }

        textFieldStatesMap[key ?: ""] =
            state to textFieldBuilder
    }

    return textFieldStatesMap
}
```

Everything works that you can shift between screens and also you can go to previous screen but issues that i am facing when going back and forth data is not preserved and also reaching the finish point or the last point where i log the json i get only fields of the last step. I tried to add remember and a couple of different approaches but seems to be stuck. any insight help here.